# Why i get NAN value when storing mmioRead result in double?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7, wav, nan

Why i get **NAN** value when trying to read .wav file and directly store it sample data in **double**? Before thinking about using this i was store the sample data in **smallint** and then convert it to double by dividing it with 32768.0 (there is no **NAN** value) but later on i got accuracy problem with rounding off when converting it back to wav file.

```
SetLength(buf, ckiData.cksize);
mmioRead(HMMIO, PAnsiChar(buf), ckiData.cksize);
```

Where buf are array of double. Weren't it allowed to directly storing it into array of double?

Comment: Why are you using floating points to process audio samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the raw sample data really is 64-bit doubles (what audio format are you using that does that?), then yes, you can directly read into an array of doubles, eg:

```
var
  buf: array of Double;

SetLength(buf, ckiData.cksize div SizeOf(Double));
mmioRead(HMMIO, PAnsiChar(buf), Length(buf) * SizeOf(Double));
```

However, most audio formats do not use doubles, so you have to first read into a suitable buffer using the correct data type (Smallint for 16-bit PCM, for example), then convert the samples afterwards.

Comment: Yes it's a wav file. I see then, then it mean if i'm doing process in double later in the end when writing it back to wav i have to round it again. So it may caused me a loss precision then?

Comment: Possibly. Why are you processing the audio as doubles to begin with?

Comment: i'm doing watermarking -> DWT(Haar), if i'm transforming in smallint i'm losing accuracy. Maybe i can't be helped anyway i'm supposed to do a lossless watermarking but because of that the result may miss 1 or 2 bit. but nvm maybe i need method to support this problem, anyway i just curious about it.

Comment: My company watermarks audio, but we use a custom scheme and don't use floating points to do it. We take X number of sample bytes, calculate a checksum, and overwrite one of the samples with the checksum, then move on to the next X bytes, and so on. The checksums don't hurt the audio in any way, are not heard by human ears and not apparent in waveform displays, but can be programmably detected and validated when needed.

Comment: now it's done anyway i use some more method like sync method to handle it.. my method actually to modify the transform domain and modified the sample value based on the watermark bit and it's good too, now i'm still testing it. i'm just a college student and this project is my final project. Thank you for your help anyway regards machun